# rightjs lightbox image size error

Tags: lightbox, rightjs

here's a live example of the problem - http://marksportfolio.herokuapp.com/folio/

when the rightjs lightbox loads, it loads all the images in it's min-size default square and overrides the image dimensions. Now at first I thought it was my css causing this, I was using a flex grid that modified img tags. So i disabled all the css, but it still loads in that small square, I've read the internet for anyone with similar problems, but stuff found nothing.

All that is done for each of the image link is the insertion of rel="lightbox"

help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after looking around, I realized that rightjs is becoming lovely.io and I found the equivalent to lightboxjs in the form of zoom.

http://lovely.io/packages/zoom